# One time auth code validation failed on server side - Android and PHP(Laravel Framework)

Tags: android, laravel, oauth-2.0, google-plus

We are developing an Android application and web application, with Laravel PHP framework as backend and our apps allow google sign in. Both web app and Android app is registered on google app console. Google sign in works well for web applications. In Android, I am able to get hold of one time auth using following scope

```
SCOPE = "oauth2:server:client_id:" + SERVER_CLIENT_ID + ":api_scope:" + scopeString;
```

scopeString is "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login". I send this one time auth to my server and it gets access token from google using this one time auth code. On back end, they are using this following code to get access token

```
$googleService->requestAccessToken($code)
```

The client id and client secret, set for $googleService are that of web application that is registered on google app console. The problem now server is not able to get access token from google and its always being redirected and asked to sign in again. The redirect urls are that of web apps. Our server is able to get access token when the one time auth code is sent from web application but it fails when its sent from Android. Why is it not working for Android but its working for web application? Where should we use the Android application client id and its redirect url? Right now its not being used any where. The google documentation seems to be very confusing to me. The same API is being used for both web app and Android application. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

On your server side, you need to check what the error is. I'm assuming you're using this library: https://github.com/artdarek/oauth-4-laravel

requestAccessToken looks like the right method, but you're getting some kind of failure, and then triggering a redirect. This is wrong on multiple levels. In this kind of sign in, the web server shouldn't even redirect (as you're not doing web sign in flow, you're just authenticating an out-of-browser client).

The problem you're likely having is with the redirect_uri (e.g. the second argument to the consumer factory). That defaults to the URL of the page you're on in the server, but you need to set it to something else for Android based sign in - it either shouldn't be supplied, or it should be set to the oob redirect URI: `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob`. If you update your question with you server side code I can probably point you at the line if this is unclear.

If that isn't the issue, check your client IDs match. You can't specify the Android client ID, it is inferred from the package name of your Android app the SHA1 of the signing key, so make sure there is an Android client ID with those values set up in the same console.developers.google.com project as the web client ID.